# Blender procedural texture not showing from downloaded file

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I have downloaded an ice cream node, blender file, but nothing is appearing in my viewport. In  my outliner there is some information, but no nodes are appearing or object showing the node configuration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: here is the Blend file: 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5DXWWJRS" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5DXWWJRS/)

Comment: The html code with the link is supposed to be edited into the question, I've taken the liberty to do that for you.

Comment: OK, thanks for that Gordon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is completely empty without any objects. To edit a material in the *Shader Editor* you have to select a material slot containing this material. Material slots have to be added to objects. A scene with no objects has nothing to add a material to.

The fact the scene is empty might be easier to realize if you would switch the *Outliner* window to the default *Display Mode* > *View Layer* instead of *Blender File* as it is in your scene:

[image: outliner display mode]

Also the fact that the *Properties* window doesn't have any *Object Properties*, *Object Data Properties*, *Modifier Properties*, Material Properties_ etc. tabs is an indication for an empty scene.

So, now to edit the material, you can add any mesh object into the scene, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add* > *Mesh* > *Cube*.

[image: add object]

Now you can go to the *Material Properties* tab, add the ice cream material to the object and the nodes will show in the *Shader Editor*.

[image: material in shader editor]